# Difference in differences with multiple treatments

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, causality, difference-in-difference

I work with a large unit-day (i,t) panel and want to estimate how the timing of treatment (A) affects the effectiveness of treatment (B), but I can't get my mind around how to do this correctly.

What I am after is analyzing whether the "treatment" coefficient of (B) on some outcome Y is affected when (A) is administered before (B) rather than after it.

Some background info: both treatments affect Y and are substitutes - they are expected to affect each other's effectiveness. Their relative timing is as good as random and both can happen at any point in time. In addition, they are supposed to operate in an "impulse-response" way, that is, the effect will be large on impact and will gradually die out over time so they are not treated indefinitely (although in practice, the pre/post periods of (A) and (B) will often overlap.) I am interested in the cumulative effect of treatment over several periods. The panel I work with is massive so groups with all combinations of treatments and timings (+ the never treated control group) exist.

The baseline model with dynamic effects where I just include both treatments in a single regression would look like this:
$
Y_{i,t} = \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_k A_{i,t_{A_i}^*+k}+ \sum_{k=1}^K \gamma_k B_{i,t_{B_i}^*+k}+\alpha_i+\phi_t+\epsilon_{i,t}, 
$
where $A$ and $B$ take value 1 when the respective treatment is "turned on" and $t_{A_i}^*$ and $t_{B_i}^*$ denote periods when A/B start for the unit $i$.

Does anyone know how to best model the question I described in this setup?

Best and thanks,
J.

Comment: Is treatment $A$ always before $B$ in temporal sequence?

Comment: No, whether $A$ or $B$ comes first is random. They are often close to each other though. However, some units get both, some only one and some none.

Comment: In short, so you're interested in assessing how the administration of treatment $A$ upstream affects $B$ downstream?